# Categorize data sequences continously

Tags: r

I am new to R and have a question regarding the adding of a new variable to a table. I have data sequences starting with 10 and ending with 20, which appear several times.

Is there a way to group these sequences continuously?

Example:

The data in the column looks like that

```
10 3 15 15 19 19 20 20 10 10 11 17 20  ...
```

I would like to have an output like that

```
10 group 1
3  group 1
15 group 1
15 group 1
19 group 1
19 group 1
20 group 1
20 group 1
10 group 2
10 group 2
11 group 2
17 group 2
20 group 2
...
```

Is it possible to program something like that?

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: try something like that for your column `cut(1:100, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10))`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But the first approach doesn't help because I would like to have group 3, group 4 etc. And I don't see the relation to the other post :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base R you can detect the sequences and create a grouping variable with `cumsum` and `head`:

```
df$grp <- cumsum(df$x == 10 & c(20, head(df$x, -1)) == 20)
```

gives:

> ```
> > df
>      x grp
>  1: 10   1
>  2:  3   1
>  3: 15   1
>  4: 15   1
>  5: 19   1
>  6: 19   1
>  7: 20   1
>  8: 20   1
>  9: 10   2
> 10: 10   2
> 11: 11   2
> 12: 17   2
> 13: 20   2
> ```

What this does:

- `df$x == 10` detects the `10`'s
- `c(20, head(df$x, -1)) == 20` detects whether the previous value is equal to `20`, the first value is set to `20` because there is preceding value for the first value of `df$x`
- By combining these two with `&` you get a logical value indicating which values in `df$` are equel to `10` and for which the preceding value is also equal to `20`.
- Wrapping that in `cumsum` you get a grouping value.

Or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, grp := cumsum(x == 10 & c(0, head(x, -1)) == 20)][]
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(x == 10 & lag(x, default = 20) == 20))
```

You can use `paste`/`paste0` to add text to the group-label:

```
paste0('group_', cumsum(df$x == 10 & c(20, head(df$x, -1)) == 20))
```

---

Used data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(10, 3, 15, 15, 19, 19, 20, 20, 10, 10, 11, 17, 20))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Also for the detailed answer :-) It was exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. x is your numerics and y will be your groups.

```
x<-0:20
y<-NA
df1<-data.frame(x,y)
group1<-(x>10)
group2<-(x<=10)
df1$y[group1]<-"Group1"
df1$y[group2]<-"Group2"
df1
```

Comment: This isn't giving the correct output imo, try applying this to the vector OP provided.